# C# add simple title for spreadsheet chart OpenXml

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

**Hi!!**

i'm able to write charts to my XLSX file. But i'm stuck adding a simple title for every chart. **No styles just simple plain text**.
My code is like this:

```
 String Dtitulo = "Hello chart";
 DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.Title chartTitle = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.Title();                
 chartTitle.ChartText = new ChartText();                    
 chartTitle.ChartText.RichText = new RichText();
 DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Paragraph parrafoTitulo = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Paragraph();
 DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Run run = parrafoTitulo.AppendChild(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Run());
 run.AppendChild(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Text(Dtitulo));

chartTitle.ChartText.RichText.AppendChild<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Paragraph>(parrafoTitulo);
chart.Title = chartTitle;
```

But when i open my file with excel says "**file is corrupt**" or something like that.

Comment: can you post your code that generates a non corrupt file?  Then we can help you change it to get you some titles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit late but I was faced with the same task, and I created an excel sheet and added manually a chart with a chart title, then opened the xml to understand what tags were needed. And after a while I got it working. moved everything in a small function as below:

So you can provide your chart object and the title you want to the below function and it will add the chart title.

Note:Im using [Open XML SDK 2.0 for Microsoft Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854(v=office.14).aspx)

```
private void AddChartTitle(DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.Chart chart,string title)
    {
        var ctitle = chart.AppendChild(new Title());
        var chartText = ctitle.AppendChild(new ChartText());
        var richText = chartText.AppendChild(new RichText());

        var bodyPr = richText.AppendChild(new BodyProperties());
        var lstStyle = richText.AppendChild(new ListStyle());
        var paragraph = richText.AppendChild(new Paragraph());

        var apPr = paragraph.AppendChild(new ParagraphProperties());
        apPr.AppendChild(new DefaultRunProperties());

        var run = paragraph.AppendChild(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Run());
        run.AppendChild(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.RunProperties() { Language = "en-CA" });
        run.AppendChild(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Text() { Text = title });
    }
```

And if you want a full example, you can review the official one [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc820055(v=office.14).aspx), and inject the above function in the right place (after the creation of the chart object) and it will add the chart title.