# C# add Title to word document chart OpenXml

Tags: c#, asp.net, openxml

I have implemented a BarChart with `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts` in a Word Document.

The result is a simple Chart.
I want to add a title to this Chart.
Allready tryed AddChartTitle() from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42521752/c-sharp-add-simple-title-for-spreadsheet-chart-openxml) Post.
But if I execute the resulting word file is corrupt (Word experienced an error trying to open the file...).

Here is my Code. Thanks a lot for your help!

```
 public static WordprocessingDocument CreateBarChart(WordprocessingDocument document, Dictionary<string, int> data, Paragraph paragraphToInsert, string chartName)
    {
        string title = "Blaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";// chartName;
        string idOfChart = "rId" + new Random().Next(1000000);

        //Dictionary<string, int> data = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        //data.Add("abc", 1);

        // Get MainDocumentPart of Document
        MainDocumentPart mainPart = document.MainDocumentPart;
        //mainPart.Document = new Document(new Body());

        // Create ChartPart object in Word Document
        ChartPart chartPart = mainPart.AddNewPart<ChartPart>(idOfChart);


        // the root element of chartPart 
        SeriesText header = new SeriesText(new NumericValue() { Text = "HelpHelp" });
        dc.ChartSpace chartSpace = new dc.ChartSpace();
        chartSpace.Append(new dc.EditingLanguage() { Val = "en-us" });

        // Create Chart 

        dc.Chart chart = new dc.Chart();

        chart.Append(new dc.AutoTitleDeleted() { Val = false });




        // Define the 3D view
        dc.View3D view3D = new dc.View3D();
        view3D.Append(new dc.RotateX() { Val = 30 });
        view3D.Append(new dc.RotateY() { Val = 0 });

        // Intiliazes a new instance of the PlotArea class
        dc.PlotArea plotArea = new dc.PlotArea();
        dc.BarChart barChart = plotArea.AppendChild<dc.BarChart>(new dc.BarChart(new dc.BarDirection()
        { Val = new EnumValue<dc.BarDirectionValues>(dc.BarDirectionValues.Column) },
           new dc.BarGrouping() { Val = new EnumValue<dc.BarGroupingValues>(dc.BarGroupingValues.Clustered) }
 
                             
        ));

        plotArea.Append(new dc.Layout());


        dc.ChartShapeProperties chartShapePros = new dc.ChartShapeProperties();

        uint i = 0;
        // Iterate through each key in the Dictionary collection and add the key to the chart Series
        // and add the corresponding value to the chart Values.
        foreach (string key in data.Keys)
        {
            dc.BarChartSeries barChartSeries = barChart.AppendChild<dc.BarChartSeries>(new dc.BarChartSeries(new dc.Index()
            {
                Val =
                new UInt32Value(i)
            },
                new dc.Order() { Val = new UInt32Value(i) },
                new dc.SeriesText(new dc.NumericValue() { Text = key })));

            dc.StringLiteral strLit = barChartSeries.AppendChild<dc.CategoryAxisData>(new dc.CategoryAxisData()).AppendChild<dc.StringLiteral>(new dc.StringLiteral());
            strLit.Append(new dc.PointCount() { Val = new UInt32Value(1U) });
            //strLit.AppendChild<dc.StringPoint>(new dc.StringPoint() { Index = new UInt32Value(0U) }).Append(new dc.NumericValue(title));
            dc.NumberLiteral numLit = barChartSeries.AppendChild<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.Values>(
                new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.Values()).AppendChild<dc.NumberLiteral>(new dc.NumberLiteral());
            numLit.Append(new dc.FormatCode("General"));
            numLit.Append(new dc.PointCount() { Val = new UInt32Value(1U) });
            numLit.AppendChild<dc.NumericPoint>(new dc.NumericPoint() { Index = new UInt32Value(0u) }).Append
            (new dc.NumericValue(data[key].ToString()));

            i++;
        }




        barChart.Append(new dc.AxisId() { Val = new UInt32Value(48650112u) });
        barChart.Append(new dc.AxisId() { Val = new UInt32Value(48672768u) });

        

        // Add the Category Axis.
        dc.CategoryAxis catAx = plotArea.AppendChild<dc.CategoryAxis>(new dc.CategoryAxis(new dc.AxisId()
        { Val = new UInt32Value(48650112u) }, new dc.Scaling(new dc.Orientation()
        {
            Val = new EnumValue<DocumentFormat.
            OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.OrientationValues>(DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.OrientationValues.MinMax)
        }),
           new dc.AxisPosition() { Val = new EnumValue<dc.AxisPositionValues>(dc.AxisPositionValues.Bottom) },
           new dc.TickLabelPosition() { Val = new EnumValue<dc.TickLabelPositionValues>(dc.TickLabelPositionValues.NextTo) },
           new dc.CrossingAxis() { Val = new UInt32Value(48672768U) },
           new dc.Crosses() { Val = new EnumValue<dc.CrossesValues>(dc.CrossesValues.AutoZero) },
           new dc.AutoLabeled() { Val = new BooleanValue(false) }, //TODO
           new dc.LabelAlignment() { Val = new EnumValue<dc.LabelAlignmentValues>(dc.LabelAlignmentValues.Center) },
           new dc.LabelOffset() { Val = new UInt16Value((ushort)100) }));

        // Add the Value Axis.
        dc.ValueAxis valAx = plotArea.AppendChild<dc.ValueAxis>(new dc.ValueAxis(new dc.AxisId() { Val = new UInt32Value(48672768u) },
        new dc.Scaling(new dc.Orientation()
        {
            Val = new EnumValue<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.OrientationValues>(
            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.OrientationValues.MinMax)
        }),
        new dc.AxisPosition() { Val = new EnumValue<dc.AxisPositionValues>(dc.AxisPositionValues.Left) },
        new dc.MajorGridlines(),
        new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.NumberingFormat()
        {
            FormatCode = new StringValue("General"),
            SourceLinked = new BooleanValue(true)
        }, new dc.TickLabelPosition()
        {
            Val = new EnumValue<dc.TickLabelPositionValues>
            (dc.TickLabelPositionValues.NextTo)
        }, new dc.CrossingAxis() { Val = new UInt32Value(48650112U) },
        new dc.Crosses() { Val = new EnumValue<dc.CrossesValues>(dc.CrossesValues.AutoZero) },
        new dc.CrossBetween() { Val = new EnumValue<dc.CrossBetweenValues>(dc.CrossBetweenValues.Between) }));

        // create child elements of the c:legend element
        // dc.Legend legend = new dc.Legend();
        // legend.Append(new dc.LegendPosition() { Val = dc.LegendPositionValues.Right });
        //dc.Overlay overlay = new dc.Overlay() { Val = true };
        //  legend.Append(overlay);


        dc.TextProperties textPros = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.TextProperties();
        textPros.Append(new d.BodyProperties());
        textPros.Append(new d.ListStyle());


        d.ParagraphProperties paraPros = new d.ParagraphProperties();
        d.DefaultParagraphProperties defaultParaPros = new d.DefaultParagraphProperties();
        defaultParaPros.Append(new d.LatinFont() { Typeface = "Arial", PitchFamily = 34, CharacterSet = 0 });
        defaultParaPros.Append(new d.ComplexScriptFont() { Typeface = "Arial", PitchFamily = 34, CharacterSet = 0 });
        paraPros.Append(defaultParaPros);


        d.Paragraph paragraph = new d.Paragraph();



        paragraph.Append(paraPros);
        paragraph.Append(new d.EndParagraphRunProperties() { Language = "en-Us" });

        textPros.Append(paragraph);


        AddChartLabels(barChart);




        //legend.Append(textPros);

        // Append c:view3D, c:plotArea and c:legend elements to the end of c:chart element
        chart.Append(view3D);
        chart.Append(plotArea);
        //chart.Append(legend);

        AddChartTitle(chart, "Test!!!!!!!!!!!"); // <-----------------------------------

        // Append the c:chart element to the end of c:dc.ChartSpace element
        chartSpace.Append(chart);

        // Create c:spPr Elements and fill the child elements of it
        chartShapePros = new dc.ChartShapeProperties();
        d.Outline outline = new d.Outline();
        outline.Append(new d.NoFill());
        chartShapePros.Append(outline);

        // Append c:spPr element to the end of c:dc.ChartSpace element
        chartSpace.Append(chartShapePros);

        chartPart.ChartSpace = chartSpace;

        // Generate content of the MainDocumentPart
        GeneratePartContent(mainPart, idOfChart, paragraphToInsert);

        return document;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My Solution (Chart with header and axis labels):

```
    using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
    using C = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts;
    using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
    using C14 = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Office2010.Drawing.Charts;
    using A = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing;
    using C15 = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Office2013.Drawing.Chart;
    using WP = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    
        public class WordChartGenerator
        {
            /**
             * Creates Chart for word document 
             * @document to insert chart
             * @data diagram data --> Dictionary<ChartPartName,ChartPartValue> 
             * @paragraphToInsert Paragrapht to insert the chart
             * @chartTitle title of chart 
             * @Axis1 Axis label 1 
             * @Axis2 Axis label 2 
             * @ChartTitleSize Font Size of chart title 
             * @AxisLabelSize Axis label Font size. 
             * */
            public WordprocessingDocument CreateChartForWordDoc(WordprocessingDocument Document, Dictionary<string, int> Data, WP.Paragraph ParagraphToInsert, string ChartTitle, string Axis1, string Axis2, int ChartTitleSize = 12, int AxisLabelSize = 10)
            {
    
                MainDocumentPart part = Document.MainDocumentPart;
                string id = "rId" + new Random().Next(1000000);
                GenerateChartPart(part, id, ParagraphToInsert, Data, ChartTitle, Axis1, Axis2, ChartTitleSize,AxisLabelSize);
                return Document;
    
            }
    
            /**
             * Finalized chart generation (adds chart to paragraph) 
             * @mainPart to insert chart
             * @paragraphToInsert Paragrapht to insert the chart
             * @id uniq chart diagram 
             * */
            public void FinalizeChart(MainDocumentPart mainPart, string id, WP.Paragraph paragraphToInsert)
            {
                WP.Paragraph paragraph = new WP.Paragraph() { RsidParagraphAddition = "00C75AEB", RsidRunAdditionDefault = "000F3EFF" };
                if (paragraphToInsert != null)
                    paragraph = paragraphToInsert;
    
                // Create a new run that has an inline drawing object
                WP.Run run = new WP.Run();
                WP.Drawing drawing = new WP.Drawing();
                A.Wordprocessing.Inline inline = new A.Wordprocessing.Inline();
                inline.Append(new A.Wordprocessing.Extent() { Cx = 5274310L, Cy = 3076575L });
                A.Wordprocessing.DocProperties docPros = new A.Wordprocessing.DocProperties() { Id = (UInt32Value)1U, Name = "Chart 1" };
                inline.Append(docPros);
                A.Graphic g = new A.Graphic();
                A.GraphicData graphicData = new A.GraphicData() { Uri = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chart" };
                C.ChartReference chartReference = new C.ChartReference() { Id = id }; //todo: random is not nice... 
                graphicData.Append(chartReference);
                g.Append(graphicData);
                inline.Append(g);
                drawing.Append(inline);
                run.Append(drawing);
                paragraph.Append(run);
                mainPart.Document.Body.Append(paragraph);
            }
    
            /**
             * Generates an Word Chart for a Wordprocessing document. 
             * @mPart WordProcessing Document to insert 
             * @idOfChart uniq Chart Id
             * @Paragraph where the diagramm has to be inserted
             * @data Data to insert --> Dictionary<ChartPartName,ChartPartValue> 
             * @chartTitle chart title 
             * @axis1 first axis labeling 
             * @axis2 second axis labeling 
             * @chartTitleSize Fontsize of chart Title 
             * @axisLabelSize Fontsize of axis 
             */
            private void GenerateChartPart(MainDocumentPart mPart, string idOfChart, WP.Paragraph paragraphToInsert, Dictionary<string, int> data, string chartTitle, string axis1, string axis2, int chartTitleSize = 12, int axisLabelSize = 10)
            {
                ChartPart part = mPart.AddNewPart<ChartPart>(idOfChart); //custommized 
    
    
                C.ChartSpace chartSpace1 = new C.ChartSpace();
                chartSpace1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("c", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chart");
                chartSpace1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("a", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main");
                chartSpace1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("r", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships");
                chartSpace1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("c16r2", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/06/chart");
                C.Date1904 date19041 = new C.Date1904() { Val = false };
                C.EditingLanguage editingLanguage1 = new C.EditingLanguage() { Val = "en-US" };
                C.RoundedCorners roundedCorners1 = new C.RoundedCorners() { Val = true };
    
                AlternateContent alternateContent1 = new AlternateContent();
                alternateContent1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("mc", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006");
    
                AlternateContentChoice alternateContentChoice1 = new AlternateContentChoice() { Requires = "c14" };
                alternateContentChoice1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("c14", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2007/8/2/chart");
                C14.Style style1 = new C14.Style() { Val = 102 };
    
                alternateContentChoice1.Append(style1);
    
                AlternateContentFallback alternateContentFallback1 = new AlternateContentFallback();
                C.Style style2 = new C.Style() { Val = 2 };
    
                alternateContentFallback1.Append(style2);
    
                alternateContent1.Append(alternateContentChoice1);
                alternateContent1.Append(alternateContentFallback1);
    
                C.Chart chart1 = new C.Chart();
    
                C.Title title1 = new C.Title();
    
                C.ChartText chartText1 = new C.ChartText();
    
                C.RichText richText1 = new C.RichText();
                A.BodyProperties bodyProperties1 = new A.BodyProperties();
                A.ListStyle listStyle1 = new A.ListStyle();
    
                A.Paragraph paragraph1 = new A.Paragraph();
    
                A.ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties1 = new A.ParagraphProperties();
                A.DefaultRunProperties defaultRunProperties1 = new A.DefaultRunProperties();
    
                paragraphProperties1.Append(defaultRunProperties1);
    
                A.Run run1 = new A.Run();
                A.RunProperties runProperties1 = new A.RunProperties() { Language = "de-DE", FontSize = chartTitleSize*10};
    
                A.Text text1 = new A.Text();
                text1.Text = chartTitle;
                run1.Append(runProperties1);
                run1.Append(text1);
    
                paragraph1.Append(paragraphProperties1);
                paragraph1.Append(run1);
    
                richText1.Append(bodyProperties1);
                richText1.Append(listStyle1);
                richText1.Append(paragraph1);
    
                chartText1.Append(richText1);
                C.Overlay overlay1 = new C.Overlay() { Val = false };
    
                title1.Append(chartText1);
                title1.Append(overlay1);
                C.AutoTitleDeleted autoTitleDeleted1 = new C.AutoTitleDeleted() { Val = false };
    
                C.PlotArea plotArea1 = new C.PlotArea();
                C.Layout layout1 = new C.Layout();
    
                List<C.BarChartSeries> charts = new List<C.BarChartSeries>();
    
                C.BarChart barChart1 = new C.BarChart();
                C.BarDirection barDirection1 = new C.BarDirection() { Val = C.BarDirectionValues.Column };
                C.BarGrouping barGrouping1 = new C.BarGrouping() { Val = C.BarGroupingValues.Clustered };
                C.VaryColors varyColors1 = new C.VaryColors() { Val = true };
    
    
                int i = 0;
                foreach (string key in data.Keys)
                {
    
    
                    C.BarChartSeries barChartSeries1 = new C.BarChartSeries();
                    C.Index index1 = new C.Index() { Val = Convert.ToUInt32(i) };
                    C.Order order1 = new C.Order() { Val = Convert.ToUInt32(i) };
    
                    C.SeriesText seriesText1 = new C.SeriesText();
                    C.NumericValue numericValue1 = new C.NumericValue();
                    numericValue1.Text = key;
    
                    seriesText1.Append(numericValue1);
                    C.InvertIfNegative invertIfNegative1 = new C.InvertIfNegative() { Val = true };
    
                    C.DataLabels dataLabels1 = new C.DataLabels();
    
                    C.ChartShapeProperties chartShapeProperties1 = new C.ChartShapeProperties();
                    A.NoFill noFill1 = new A.NoFill();
    
                    A.Outline outline1 = new A.Outline();
                    A.NoFill noFill2 = new A.NoFill();
    
                    outline1.Append(noFill2);
                    A.EffectList effectList1 = new A.EffectList();
    
                    chartShapeProperties1.Append(noFill1);
                    chartShapeProperties1.Append(outline1);
                    chartShapeProperties1.Append(effectList1);
                    C.ShowLegendKey showLegendKey1 = new C.ShowLegendKey() { Val = true };
                    C.ShowValue showValue1 = new C.ShowValue() { Val = true };
                    C.ShowCategoryName showCategoryName1 = new C.ShowCategoryName() { Val = false };
                    C.ShowSeriesName showSeriesName1 = new C.ShowSeriesName() { Val = true };
                    C.ShowPercent showPercent1 = new C.ShowPercent() { Val = false };
                    C.ShowBubbleSize showBubbleSize1 = new C.ShowBubbleSize() { Val = false };
                    C.ShowLeaderLines showLeaderLines1 = new C.ShowLeaderLines() { Val = false };
    
                    C.DLblsExtensionList dLblsExtensionList1 = new C.DLblsExtensionList();
    
                    C.DLblsExtension dLblsExtension1 = new C.DLblsExtension() { Uri = "{CE6537A1-D6FC-4f65-9D91-7224C49458BB}" };
                    dLblsExtension1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("c15", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2012/chart");
                    C15.ShowLeaderLines showLeaderLines2 = new C15.ShowLeaderLines() { Val = false };
    
                    dLblsExtension1.Append(showLeaderLines2);
    
                    dLblsExtensionList1.Append(dLblsExtension1);
    
                    dataLabels1.Append(chartShapeProperties1);
                    dataLabels1.Append(showLegendKey1);
                    dataLabels1.Append(showValue1);
                    dataLabels1.Append(showCategoryName1);
                    dataLabels1.Append(showSeriesName1);
                    dataLabels1.Append(showPercent1);
                    dataLabels1.Append(showBubbleSize1);
                    dataLabels1.Append(showLeaderLines1);
                    dataLabels1.Append(dLblsExtensionList1);
    
                    C.CategoryAxisData categoryAxisData1 = new C.CategoryAxisData();
    
                    C.StringLiteral stringLiteral1 = new C.StringLiteral();
                    C.PointCount pointCount1 = new C.PointCount() { Val = (UInt32Value)1U };
    
                    stringLiteral1.Append(pointCount1);
    
                    categoryAxisData1.Append(stringLiteral1);
    
                    C.Values values1 = new C.Values();
    
                    C.NumberLiteral numberLiteral1 = new C.NumberLiteral();
                    C.FormatCode formatCode1 = new C.FormatCode();
                    formatCode1.Text = "General";
                    C.PointCount pointCount2 = new C.PointCount() { Val = (UInt32Value)1U };
    
                    C.NumericPoint numericPoint1 = new C.NumericPoint() { Index = (UInt32Value)0U };
                    C.NumericValue numericValue2 = new C.NumericValue();
                    numericValue2.Text = data[key].ToString();
    
                    numericPoint1.Append(numericValue2);
    
                    numberLiteral1.Append(formatCode1);
                    numberLiteral1.Append(pointCount2);
                    numberLiteral1.Append(numericPoint1);
    
                    values1.Append(numberLiteral1);
    
                    C.BarSerExtensionList barSerExtensionList1 = new C.BarSerExtensionList();
    
                    C.BarSerExtension barSerExtension1 = new C.BarSerExtension() { Uri = "{C3380CC4-5D6E-409C-BE32-E72D297353CC}" };
                    barSerExtension1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("c16", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/chart");
    
                    OpenXmlUnknownElement openXmlUnknownElement1 = OpenXmlUnknownElement.CreateOpenXmlUnknownElement("<c16:uniqueId val=\"{" + i.ToString().PadLeft(8, '0') + "-3253-4028-997C-A2631CC5E43E}\" xmlns:c16=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/chart\" />");
    
                    barSerExtension1.Append(openXmlUnknownElement1);
    
                    barSerExtensionList1.Append(barSerExtension1);
    
                    barChartSeries1.Append(index1);
                    barChartSeries1.Append(order1);
                    barChartSeries1.Append(seriesText1);
                    barChartSeries1.Append(invertIfNegative1);
                    barChartSeries1.Append(dataLabels1);
                    barChartSeries1.Append(categoryAxisData1);
                    barChartSeries1.Append(values1);
                    barChartSeries1.Append(barSerExtensionList1);
    
                    charts.Add(barChartSeries1);
                    barChart1.Append(barChartSeries1);
    
                    i++;
                }
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
                C.DataLabels dataLabels4 = new C.DataLabels();
                C.ShowLegendKey showLegendKey4 = new C.ShowLegendKey() { Val = true };
                C.ShowValue showValue4 = new C.ShowValue() { Val = true };
                C.ShowCategoryName showCategoryName4 = new C.ShowCategoryName() { Val = false };
                C.ShowSeriesName showSeriesName4 = new C.ShowSeriesName() { Val = true };
                C.ShowPercent showPercent4 = new C.ShowPercent() { Val = false };
                C.ShowBubbleSize showBubbleSize4 = new C.ShowBubbleSize() { Val = false };
    
                dataLabels4.Append(showLegendKey4);
                dataLabels4.Append(showValue4);
                dataLabels4.Append(showCategoryName4);
                dataLabels4.Append(showSeriesName4);
                dataLabels4.Append(showPercent4);
                dataLabels4.Append(showBubbleSize4);
                C.GapWidth gapWidth1 = new C.GapWidth() { Val = (UInt16Value)150U };
                C.AxisId axisId1 = new C.AxisId() { Val = (UInt32Value)48650112U };
                C.AxisId axisId2 = new C.AxisId() { Val = (UInt32Value)48672768U };
    
                barChart1.Append(barDirection1);
                barChart1.Append(barGrouping1);
                barChart1.Append(varyColors1);
    
    
                /*foreach(C.BarChartSeries chart in charts){
                    barChart1.Append(chart);
                }*/
    
                barChart1.Append(dataLabels4);
                barChart1.Append(gapWidth1);
                barChart1.Append(axisId1);
                barChart1.Append(axisId2);
    
                C.CategoryAxis categoryAxis1 = new C.CategoryAxis();
                C.AxisId axisId3 = new C.AxisId() { Val = (UInt32Value)48650112U };
    
                C.Scaling scaling1 = new C.Scaling();
                C.Orientation orientation1 = new C.Orientation() { Val = C.OrientationValues.MinMax };
    
                scaling1.Append(orientation1);
                C.Delete delete1 = new C.Delete() { Val = true };
                C.AxisPosition axisPosition1 = new C.AxisPosition() { Val = C.AxisPositionValues.Bottom };
    
                C.Title title2 = new C.Title();
    
                C.ChartText chartText2 = new C.ChartText();
    
                C.RichText richText2 = new C.RichText();
                A.BodyProperties bodyProperties2 = new A.BodyProperties();
                A.ListStyle listStyle2 = new A.ListStyle();
    
                A.Paragraph paragraph2 = new A.Paragraph();
    
                A.ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties2 = new A.ParagraphProperties();
                A.DefaultRunProperties defaultRunProperties2 = new A.DefaultRunProperties();
    
                paragraphProperties2.Append(defaultRunProperties2);
    
                A.Run run2 = new A.Run();
                A.RunProperties runProperties2 = new A.RunProperties() { Language = "de-DE", FontSize = axisLabelSize*10 };
                A.Text text2 = new A.Text();
                text2.Text = axis2;
    
                run2.Append(runProperties2);
                run2.Append(text2);
    
                paragraph2.Append(paragraphProperties2);
                paragraph2.Append(run2);
    
                richText2.Append(bodyProperties2);
                richText2.Append(listStyle2);
                richText2.Append(paragraph2);
    
                chartText2.Append(richText2);
                C.Overlay overlay2 = new C.Overlay() { Val = false };
    
                title2.Append(chartText2);
                title2.Append(overlay2);
                C.NumberingFormat numberingFormat1 = new C.NumberingFormat() { FormatCode = "General", SourceLinked = false };
                C.MajorTickMark majorTickMark1 = new C.MajorTickMark() { Val = C.TickMarkValues.Cross };
                C.MinorTickMark minorTickMark1 = new C.MinorTickMark() { Val = C.TickMarkValues.Cross };
                C.TickLabelPosition tickLabelPosition1 = new C.TickLabelPosition() { Val = C.TickLabelPositionValues.NextTo };
                C.CrossingAxis crossingAxis1 = new C.CrossingAxis() { Val = (UInt32Value)48672768U };
                C.Crosses crosses1 = new C.Crosses() { Val = C.CrossesValues.AutoZero };
                C.AutoLabeled autoLabeled1 = new C.AutoLabeled() { Val = false };
                C.LabelAlignment labelAlignment1 = new C.LabelAlignment() { Val = C.LabelAlignmentValues.Center };
                C.LabelOffset labelOffset1 = new C.LabelOffset() { Val = (UInt16Value)100U };
                C.NoMultiLevelLabels noMultiLevelLabels1 = new C.NoMultiLevelLabels() { Val = true };
    
                categoryAxis1.Append(axisId3);
                categoryAxis1.Append(scaling1);
                categoryAxis1.Append(delete1);
                categoryAxis1.Append(axisPosition1);
                categoryAxis1.Append(title2);
                categoryAxis1.Append(numberingFormat1);
                categoryAxis1.Append(majorTickMark1);
                categoryAxis1.Append(minorTickMark1);
                categoryAxis1.Append(tickLabelPosition1);
                categoryAxis1.Append(crossingAxis1);
                categoryAxis1.Append(crosses1);
                categoryAxis1.Append(autoLabeled1);
                categoryAxis1.Append(labelAlignment1);
                categoryAxis1.Append(labelOffset1);
                categoryAxis1.Append(noMultiLevelLabels1);
    
                C.ValueAxis valueAxis1 = new C.ValueAxis();
                C.AxisId axisId4 = new C.AxisId() { Val = (UInt32Value)48672768U };
    
                C.Scaling scaling2 = new C.Scaling();
                C.Orientation orientation2 = new C.Orientation() { Val = C.OrientationValues.MinMax };
    
                scaling2.Append(orientation2);
                C.Delete delete2 = new C.Delete() { Val = true };
                C.AxisPosition axisPosition2 = new C.AxisPosition() { Val = C.AxisPositionValues.Left };
                C.MajorGridlines majorGridlines1 = new C.MajorGridlines();
    
                C.Title title3 = new C.Title();
    
                C.ChartText chartText3 = new C.ChartText();
    
                C.RichText richText3 = new C.RichText();
                A.BodyProperties bodyProperties3 = new A.BodyProperties();
                A.ListStyle listStyle3 = new A.ListStyle();
    
                A.Paragraph paragraph3 = new A.Paragraph();
    
                A.ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties3 = new A.ParagraphProperties();
                A.DefaultRunProperties defaultRunProperties3 = new A.DefaultRunProperties();
    
                paragraphProperties3.Append(defaultRunProperties3);
    
                A.Run run3 = new A.Run();
                A.RunProperties runProperties3 = new A.RunProperties() { Language = "de-DE", FontSize = axisLabelSize * 10 };
                A.Text text3 = new A.Text();
                text3.Text = axis1;
    
                run3.Append(runProperties3);
                run3.Append(text3);
    
                paragraph3.Append(paragraphProperties3);
                paragraph3.Append(run3);
    
                richText3.Append(bodyProperties3);
                richText3.Append(listStyle3);
                richText3.Append(paragraph3);
    
                chartText3.Append(richText3);
                C.Overlay overlay3 = new C.Overlay() { Val = false };
    
                title3.Append(chartText3);
                title3.Append(overlay3);
                C.NumberingFormat numberingFormat2 = new C.NumberingFormat() { FormatCode = "General", SourceLinked = true };
                C.MajorTickMark majorTickMark2 = new C.MajorTickMark() { Val = C.TickMarkValues.Cross };
                C.MinorTickMark minorTickMark2 = new C.MinorTickMark() { Val = C.TickMarkValues.Cross };
                C.TickLabelPosition tickLabelPosition2 = new C.TickLabelPosition() { Val = C.TickLabelPositionValues.NextTo };
                C.CrossingAxis crossingAxis2 = new C.CrossingAxis() { Val = (UInt32Value)48650112U };
                C.Crosses crosses2 = new C.Crosses() { Val = C.CrossesValues.AutoZero };
                C.CrossBetween crossBetween1 = new C.CrossBetween() { Val = C.CrossBetweenValues.Between };
    
                valueAxis1.Append(axisId4);
                valueAxis1.Append(scaling2);
                valueAxis1.Append(delete2);
                valueAxis1.Append(axisPosition2);
                valueAxis1.Append(majorGridlines1);
                valueAxis1.Append(title3);
                valueAxis1.Append(numberingFormat2);
                valueAxis1.Append(majorTickMark2);
                valueAxis1.Append(minorTickMark2);
                valueAxis1.Append(tickLabelPosition2);
                valueAxis1.Append(crossingAxis2);
                valueAxis1.Append(crosses2);
                valueAxis1.Append(crossBetween1);
    
                plotArea1.Append(layout1);
                plotArea1.Append(barChart1);
                plotArea1.Append(categoryAxis1);
                plotArea1.Append(valueAxis1);
                C.PlotVisibleOnly plotVisibleOnly1 = new C.PlotVisibleOnly() { Val = true };
                C.DisplayBlanksAs displayBlanksAs1 = new C.DisplayBlanksAs() { Val = C.DisplayBlanksAsValues.Zero };
                C.ShowDataLabelsOverMaximum showDataLabelsOverMaximum1 = new C.ShowDataLabelsOverMaximum() { Val = true };
    
                chart1.Append(title1);
                chart1.Append(autoTitleDeleted1);
                chart1.Append(plotArea1);
                chart1.Append(plotVisibleOnly1);
                chart1.Append(displayBlanksAs1);
                chart1.Append(showDataLabelsOverMaximum1);
    
                C.ShapeProperties shapeProperties1 = new C.ShapeProperties();
    
                A.Outline outline4 = new A.Outline();
                A.NoFill noFill7 = new A.NoFill();
    
                outline4.Append(noFill7);
    
                shapeProperties1.Append(outline4);
    
                chartSpace1.Append(date19041);
                chartSpace1.Append(editingLanguage1);
                chartSpace1.Append(roundedCorners1);
                chartSpace1.Append(alternateContent1);
                chartSpace1.Append(chart1);
                chartSpace1.Append(shapeProperties1);
    
                part.ChartSpace = chartSpace1;
    
    
                FinalizeChart(mPart, idOfChart, paragraphToInsert);
            }
    
    
    
    
        
    }
```